# git removes and adds the same line

Tags: git

I'm reviewing my changes using `git diff` and found that a line that I didn't touch is considered as a one that was both removed and added...

The lines are identical. How does this happen?

```
             for f in self.get_remote_file_list(remote_path):
                 scp_client.get(os.path.join(f), local_path)
-        self._log_info('Download done.')        <-----
\ No newline at end of file
+        self._log_info('Download done.')        <-----
+    my changes...
```

This is the current state of the file surrounding said line:

```
    for f in self.get_remote_file_list(remote_path):
        scp_client.get(os.path.join(f), local_path)
self._log_info('Download done.')
```

Comment: `\ No newline at end of file`?

Comment: I don't get it. It's not part of the file...

Comment: It probably added one, and the diff picked it up as a change on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Newline is an actual character code, 0x0a,  it's part of and ends each text line. So one of the self.log lines doesn't have one, one does. They're different.

Yes, the convention is arbitrary, about like which colors mean what on traffic signs, you could say newlines separate text lines and aren't part of them, the signs would still mean the same thing and most people would figure them out without caring much, but it does matter some. Maybe more like the difference between yellow and white speed limits than red or some other color stop signs, still, convention matters, pay attention to detail.

Comment: It doesn't matter much in curly-brace languages like C, Java or Javascript, but it certainly matters in languages that are whitespace-sensitive like Python, the language that is apparently being represented in the OP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey python's for sure not my forte, where does python complain or misbehave at the absence of an eol at eof?

Comment: End-of-line is whitespace, and therefore a significant character for Python.  Its absence would almost certainly be meaningful.